# Вывод гиперссылки вместо текста

Tags: mysql, веб-программирование, php, ссылки, echo

Есть кусок `php` кода:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['id_cat']){
$id_cat=$_GET['id_cat'];
$sql_cat = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id_cat='$id_cat'";
$query_cat=mysql_query($sql_cat) or die(mysql_error());
$row_cat=mysql_fetch_array($query_cat);
?>
<?=$row_cat['name_cat']?>
```

В результате последний оператор в этом коде вместо текста выводит гиперссылку:

[image]

а необходим текст вместо гиперссылки Категория 1_1.

Answer (score 1):

Просмотрите, пожалуйста, ваш html-код выше. Возможно, вы где-то не закрыли тег гиперссылки.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно так:

```
<?=$row_cat['text_cat']?>
```

Там нужно указать ту ячейку базы которая отвечает за текст.